# Как конвертировать файл xls в csv с разделителем ";"?

Tags: c#, oledb, interop, office-interop

Как конвертировать файл xls в csv с разделителем ";"?

У меня получилось конвертировать файл xls в csv с разделителем ",", но мне необходимо чтобы разделителем был знак ";".

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(@way + filename + "." + typeFile);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = wb.Sheets[1];
        wb.SaveAs(@way+filename+".csv", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows);
        wb.Close(false);
        app.Quit();
```

Просто побежать циклом по всем ячейкам и заменить "," на ";" не вариант, потому что в ячейках содержится много значимых   ",".

Comment: Создайте спецификацию экспорта с нужными опциями, и используйте её.

Comment: Как это сделать? Пример можно?

Comment: Сделайте проще. Вставьте в книгу ещё один лист (или используйте незадействованную колонку на существующем листе), на нём с помощью функции `СЦЕПИТЬ` соберите строку для экспорта со всеми нужными разделителями и кавычками, экспортируйте полученную колонку, а потом прибейте. Это будет полностью управляемо и не будет зависеть от региональных настроек станции и прочей ерунды. Только приводите каждое поле явно к нужному виду - а то с экселя станется вместо даты нарисовать число внутреннего формата...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вроде так должно быть:

```
wb.SaveAs(@way+filename+".csv", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows, Local: true);
```

Comment: Да, это помогло. Спасибо!